# How to prevent html tags in nicEditor?

Tags: javascript, html, textarea, nicedit

I want to prevent writing html tags in nicEditor.

```
<div id="sample">
  <script  type="text/javascript" src="http://js.nicedit.com/nicEdit-latest.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
        bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() { nicEditors.allTextAreas() });
  //]]>
  </script>
  <textarea onblur="this.value = this.value.replace(/<\/?[^>]+>/gi, '')" name="process" style="width: 300px; height: 100px;" id="process">
         hello <b>world</b>
  </textarea>
</div>
```

I have tried above regex..but it doesn't work..
I am using the same regex `onblur="this.value = this.value.replace(/<\/?[^>]+>/gi, '')"` for simple textbox.and it works fine.

I also want to know that, is it the proper way to prevent html tags from user inputs for security purpose?

Comment: @Nirali Joshi, for me your code works well. What is the exact problem?

Comment: @caligula for me it shows the same as hello <b>world</b>..it means it also saves hello <b>world</b> into database.

Comment: @Nirali Joshi, in my FF it removes `<b></b>`. May be `submit` occurs before `blur` ?

Comment: @caligula , how it is possible??submit before blur?..first it loses focus..and then submits.

Comment: @Nirali Joshi, for example if you trigger `submit` via `js`, or you press `enter` when `input` has a focus, although not in `textarea`

Comment: @caligula  ,no no that is not an issue.first i m writing into textarea and then presses submit button.so when i press submit, textarea automatically loses focus.

Comment: @Nirali Joshi, consider to provide jsfiddle with your issue. Are you sure there is no errors in console and script is still executing?

Comment: @caligula yes, there is not a single error..simply it stores ` hello &lt;b&gt;world&lt;/b&gt;` into database.

Comment: @Nirali Joshi, can you test the order of priority of the events? try to attach two handlers `form.submit` and `textarea.blur` and `e.preventDefault` inside `submit`. And use inside both of them `console.log('submit')` and `console.log('blur')` to see which one fires before

Comment: @caligula yes u r right..first it calls submit event...infact it only calls submit event.but how it is possible??y it doesn'ty call blur event of textarea???

Comment: @Nirali Joshi, so I can post that comment as an answer?

Comment: @caligula :)crazy for reputation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to test the order of priority of the events. Attach two handlers `form.submit` and `textarea.blur` and `e.preventDefault` inside `submit`. And use inside both of them `console.log('submit')` and `console.log('blur')` to see which one fires before. Cause the problem may be in the `submit` which fires before `blur`

Comment: yes u r right..but can u please tell me..why this happens?why it doesn't call onblur event of textarea?

Comment: @Nirali Joshi, tell me what browser you are using? I tested it in FF, chrome, IE9 and `blur` fires before `submit`

Comment: try to check may be your form is submitted via js. For instance, `$('textarea').blur(function(){$(this).parent().submit()})`

Comment: sorry...it is an browser issue.i told u chrome but it was my mistake..i m workin on remote desktop so there i am using safari.i forgot that. :P now i have tried  in chrome.and it calls blur first. stupid safari..:)

Comment: Almost definitely it's somehow related to remote desktop. I use Safari on Windows

Comment: i m also use safari on windows at remote desktop..i m using safari version 5.1.7  what version u r using?

Comment: May be bug in the remote desktop. Try other browsers, if the issue persists then 100% the bug